# jquery ajax call results in error and xhr.status == 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

u just wanted to implement a very basic download counter.
when clicking on the link an ajax request should be sent to the server and after this the download should start.

```
    <a href="<?= $update->link ?>" onClick="downloadCount(<?= $update->id ?>);"><?php echo img(array("height" => "24", "src" => "images/btn_free.png")); ?></a>
```

That's how i generate the link.

```
function downloadCount(id_) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '<?= base_url() ?>index.php/updates/incCount/' + id_.toString(),
      success: function() { return true },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                            alert(xhr.status);
                            alert(thrownError);
                        }
    });
```

url is correct (if i copy the url everything is ok)
but when clicking the link i just got the 2 alerts (1st with 0 and 2nd is empty)

when i add `return false;` in the onClick part the link isn executed and the ajax call is successfull
when i add `return false;` to my function the link proceeds everytime (WHY??) and the ajax call returns in an error.

The domain is the same so this should not be the reason...
I'm kinda confused due this normally very easy task >_<

Comment: The domain is the same, and the protocol is the same, and the port is the same? Does `base_url()` give a trailing slash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clicking the link causes the browser to navigate to another page, this aborts any outstanding ajax requests - which is why you're getting an error.

If you wish for your `downloadCount` function to determine whether the page should reload or not, you need to *return* this value from your handler:

```
onClick="return downloadCount(<?= $update->id ?>);"
```

Comment: I already thought the same but why is the browser still navigating to another site when I add `return false;` AFTER the ajax function call?

Answer (score 0):

For the jQuery way, use preventDefault().

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: `return false;` will actually do a `e.preventDefault()` (& `e.stopPropagation()`)

Comment: @Johan Indeed, and if you don't want to do `stopPropagation`, you shouldn't, because it prevents event delegation.

Comment: @Johan, do we need to do e.stopPropagation() here ?